# Include a variable in a table when publishing a MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, publish

I would like to publish some tables of categorical data with variable numbers of categories, so I need a generic table. Any idea how I could publish a generic table using, e.g. the publish-function? I could have the output as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this from the MATLAB Central File Exchange:

[Printing Variables to HTML Tables in Published Code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14453-printing-variables-to-html-tables-in-published-code)

Comment: This solves the problem. A solution was particularly hard to find by searching, tried google for sure many times, and searching matlab documentation for 'table' but somehow didn't come across 'uitable' command in matlab. Particularly happy to be able to continue with my project from this solution, thank you!